# Java spring boot rest service struggle

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

After few years I got back to Java to try to implement RESTful WS using Java. I have found plenty of tutorials and articles about implementing it using *Spring* and it's **Spring boot** extension on top of *Maven*. After first problems with setting all up I finally have a WS that is running and is accessible (e.g. from CLI using `curl`).

Unfortunately I am getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` exceptions, with these two messages:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that position [1] did not exist

and

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that name [cart_id] did not exist

Here's my shortened `Entity` class:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "cart", catalog = "table1", schema = "")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Cart.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Cart c"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Cart.findByCartId", query = "SELECT c FROM Cart c WHERE c.cartId = :cartId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Cart.findByBarcode", query = "SELECT c FROM Cart c WHERE c.barcode = :barcode"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Cart.findByCartTypeId", query = "SELECT c FROM Cart c WHERE c.cartTypeId = :cartTypeId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Cart.findByCartStyleId", query = "SELECT c FROM Cart c WHERE c.cartStyleId = :cartStyleId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Cart.findByCartName", query = "SELECT c FROM Cart c WHERE c.cartName = :cartName"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Cart.findByNotificationId", query = "SELECT c FROM Cart c WHERE c.notificationId = :notificationId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Cart.findByCartContentId", query = "SELECT c FROM Cart c WHERE c.cartContentId = :cartContentId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Cart.findByStationId", query = "SELECT c FROM Cart c WHERE c.stationId = :stationId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Cart.findByUserId", query = "SELECT c FROM Cart c WHERE c.userId = :userId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Cart.findByStatus", query = "SELECT c FROM Cart c WHERE c.status = :status")})
public class Cart implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "cart_id")
    private Long cartId;

    @Size(max = 50)
    private String barcode;

    @Column(name = "notification_id")
    private Integer notificationId;

    // other properties, getters and setters follow ...
}
```

Here the repository:

```java
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface CartDAO extends CrudRepository<Cart, Long> {

    /**
     * Returns cart by it's ID.
     * @param cartId
     * @return Cart
     */
    public Cart findByCartId(@Param("cart_id") Long cartId);

    /**
     * Returns cart by it's barcode (EAN).
     * @param barcode
     * @return Cart
     */
    public Cart findByBarcode(String barcode);

    /**
     * Returns all the carts belonging to notification (by notification ID).
     * @param notificationId
     * @return List of Carts
     */
    public List<Cart> findByNotificationId(@Param("notification_id") Integer notificationId);

}
```

And here's the controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/carts")
public class CartController {

    @Autowired
    private CartDAO cartDao;

    @RequestMapping(value="/id/{cartId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Cart getCartById(@PathVariable Long cartId) {
        return cartDao.findByCartId(cartId);
//        return cartDao.findOne(cartId);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/ean/{barcode}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Cart getCartByBarcode(@PathVariable String barcode) {
        return cartDao.findByBarcode(barcode);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/notification/{notificationId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Cart> getCartByNotification(@PathVariable Integer notificationId) {
        return cartDao.findByNotificationId(notificationId);
    }
}
```

If I call the WS with cmd `curl -g localhost:8080/carts/id/1` or `curl -g localhost:8080/carts/notification/1` I got the exception with the second msg (for name `[cart_id]` or `[notification_id]`). If I call the cmd `curl -g localhost:8080/carts/ean/2550000017884` I got the exception with the first msg (for `position [1]`).

The DB table looks like:

```
cart
===========================================
cart_id            INT (PK, auto_increment)
notification_id    INT (FK)
barcode            VARCHAR(13) (NOT NULL, UNIQUE)
...
```

However if I switch comment for the two lines in `CartController.getCartById()` (i.e. let `return cartDao.findOne(cartId);` to be invoked instead of `return cartDao.findByCartId(cartId);`), then I finally can see a valid response without exception.

But what am I doing wrong here? Obviously I am missing something (and all the tutorials as well).

PS: I have created all the entities using the `persistance unit` - I have let the PU to connect to my DB and to create all the entities for me. I liked to work this way back in the days as PU can handle very quickly changes on both sides and mirror them on the other. With the help of PU I also have lot of `@NamedQueries` which could be of help but since all the *spring-boot* tutorials are working with *JPA repository* I don't know either how to call those named queries from *Persistence*...

EDIT: adding the dependencies part of my `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <!-- Get the dependencies of a web application -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- DB -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Remove the `@Param` from the query methods, those are only  needed if you use `@Query` (as explained in the reference guide). Also your `findByCartId` is the same as the default `findOne` so it is pretty useless imho.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks, that helped to get rid of *parameter name* exception msg, now I am getting only **`Parameter with that position [1] did not exist;`** for all three methods...

Comment: I would for starters remove the `findByCartId` that reduces your problems by 33% :) (It also adds nothing over the `findOne` method. Could you add the full stack trace and maybe your pom (at least dependencies section of the pom).

Comment: @M.Deinum I implemented the `findByCartId` first as my `@Id` was of type `Integer`. Then I found out there's native repository's method `findById` that is accepting `Long` so I changed it in my entity to `Long` to try it out... If i find out that `findByCartId` as `Integer` is working, I'll return my `@Id` to `Integer`...

Comment: @M.Deinum dependencies from `pom.xml` added.

Comment: You are confusing, your Id is of type long (as well in the entity as in the repository definition). If the id is of a different type your repository should also reflect that! You are also mentioning named queries you don't happen to have a named query named `findByCartId` do you (or one of the other method names!).

Comment: Could you include your full `Cart` class (included the `@NamedQueries`...

Comment: Previously my  Id was of type `Integer` everywhere. After finding out `findOne` I change it to `Long` everywhere. I didn't put here my named queries as they are taking few more lines and are not the main topic of my question... Or should they be?

Comment: There is no findById in a spring data repository, there is a `findOne`... Which takes an id of the type you specify it to be...

Comment: Please add the named queries as requested...

Comment: @M.Deinum Added them. Why are they so important? They weren't used in any tutorial, I just have them thanks to persistence... But JPA is used then to access the DB...

Comment: Because they are named `Cart.findByCartId` and if you have a repository for `Cart` with a method `findByCartId` it will execute the named query and NOT create a query. So instead of queries being created it tries to execute your named queries. So basically your whole problem comes from the automatic generation of all those queries. Remove them and it will work, or reinstate the `@Param` but match the parameter names in the query not the column names...

Comment: @M.Deinum This solved it!!! Hmm, I didn't know it could be that simple!!! So in the end I can even use my named queries, that's perfect!!! Thank you so much!!! If you could sum it all up into a nice answer (as I am missing lot of theory here) I'll accept and upvote it ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the `@Param` works (and not giving an error) indicates that a pre defined query is executed. Without a query the `@Param` would fail.

Spring Data uses a strategy to determine which query to execute by default it uses `CREATE_IF_NOT_FOUND` [lookup strategy](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-lookup-strategies). It first tries to find a pre-defined query, this can be either a `@Query` on the method or a `@NamedQuery` for JPA (in the latter case it is looking for a `<entity-name>.<method-name>` named query). If neither of these applies it will create a query based on the method.

In your case you have a named query with the name `Cart.findByCartId` (and the same applies to the other methods as well). Spring Data detects this query and will execute it. Due to your `@Param` it tries to find a parameter named `cart_id` but the name is actually `cartId` (see the named query).

To solve your issue either
1. Fix the `@Param` annotations in your method to point to the correct parameter names
2. Remove the `@Param` and `@NamedQuery`s
3. Switch Spring Data JPA to the `CREATE` lookup strategy and remove the `@Param`.

Comment: I went with the first solution. This gives me the possibility to use the lookup strategy for creating new queries (if missing) and to use the named queries as well which I like already from the times I was working with Persistence. Thank you again!